# How to group and count in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, group-by

I am currently trying to create graph statistics for jobs in a PBS. I have a jobs model that has many fields, among them is a "Group" field. I would like to know how many jobs each group has executed. For that, I need the following query:

```
SELECT 
jobs.`group`,
COUNT(`group`) AS 'number_of_jobs'
FROM jobs
GROUP BY jobs.`group`
```

Which returns 2 columns, the group name and how many jobs that group has executed, whoever, I am unable to do so in Ruby on rails. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group is keyword for mysql so use (**`**) backtics for it

```
Job.find(
          :all,
          :select => '`group`, COUNT(`group`) AS number_of_jobs',
          :group  => '`group`'
      )
```

No check though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have model named Job for jobs tables

```
Job.find(
          :all,
          :select => 'group, COUNT(group) AS number_of_jobs',
          :group  => 'group'
      )
```

Comment: For some reason this code gave me an SQL syntax error...it produced the following query:

SELECT group, COUNT(group) AS number_of_jobs FROM `jobs`  GROUP BY group.

However I tweaked it a bit, an this worked:

 Job.all({
  :select => "jobs.group AS name, COUNT('group') AS contador",
  :group =>"jobs.group"})

But that doesnt seem to be the "rails way". Thanks!